# Card image alignment

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to have the images in my cards be fixed to the top of the card body. I have tried bottom: 0 but it doesn't work. I want the card body to be of fixed height and fixed to the bottom (which is working). But I want the images to be fixed to the top as they have different sizes and will scale differently. Please someone help.[image]

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">

            <img class="card-img-top fluid-img" src="briefcase.png" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Suit</h5>
                 <p class="card-text">Professional, business executive look.</p>
                 <p class="text-center">€299</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Add to cart</a>
```

```css
.card-img-top {
  width: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: calc(0.25rem - 1px);
  border-top-right-radius: calc(0.25rem - 1px);
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 0;
  height: 650px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: border-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.card-body {
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 1.25rem;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">

      <img class="card-img-top fluid-img" src="briefcase.png" alt="Card image cap">
     <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Suit</h5>
         <p class="card-text">Professional, business executive look.</p>
         <p class="text-center">€299</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Add to cart</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried the CSS property "position:absolute;top:0%;"

Comment: I have I want the briefcase to be fixed at the top of the card body like the suit is.

Comment: It would be very helpful if we could see the code in order to interpret what exactly is happening and where the issue is, please edit in the code related to this scenario.

Comment: Try to work with your CSS and the size of your image

Comment: If I set a fixed height and width, it will distort the images. I want the images to be responsive but be situated just above the card body.

Comment: Could we see the style sheet, the properties of the class that these elements have is kinda important.

Comment: I'm using default bootstrap 4 css.

Comment: Well the reason for these formatting failures lies within those classes, without being able to see them, im not sure how anyone could help besides completely redesigning the front end from scratch.

Comment: Ok I have added the css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `position:absolute` for card-body

```
.card-body{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
 }
```

```css
.card-img-top {
  width: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: calc(0.25rem - 1px);
  border-top-right-radius: calc(0.25rem - 1px);
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 0;
  height: 650px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: border-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.card-body{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">

      <img class="card-img-top fluid-img" src="briefcase.png" alt="Card image cap">
     <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Suit</h5>
         <p class="card-text">Professional, business executive look.</p>
         <p class="text-center">€299</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Add to cart</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have added that already and it works but I want the card img to be fixed to the top of the card body

Comment: Is you want image within `.card-body`?

Comment: Just do top:0; then adam, the position:absolute is the big part, i mentioned this in my very first comment ont he OP.

Comment: Hi guys, yes position absolute done the trick. I had to offset it by the height of thr card body from the bottom (218px) and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you need use flexbox

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="wrapper-image">
        <img class="card-img-top fluid-img" src="briefcase.png" alt="Card image cap">
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Suit</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Professional, business executive look.</p>
    <p class="text-center">€299</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Add to cart</a>
  </div>
</div>

.wrapper-image {
    height: 18rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```

in this case the wrapper imagem will have `18rem height`, it's bigger than image so the align itens property will put the imagem on the start div (top), you can too use `center` and `flex-end` instead `flex-start`, the display flex allows you use the `align-items` and `justify-content` property (this allows you to position the image horizontally)
the `display flex` is also useful to put all inside a tag on the same line, so if inside te wrapper-image you put two image them will be shown side by side, for correct it you can use `flex-direction: column`
If it don
you can see more about flexbox [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)
If this was not useful, better show your code, if possible put it in the codepen so I can be more useful